# Listing items in a figure caption

Tags: captions, enumerate

I'm trying to add a list of items to a figure caption. I've got a BUNCH of packages that I'm using in this paper, so I've included all of the packages in case there are any incompatibility problems with them.

The packages I'm using are these:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{carbohydrates}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{epsfig}  
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

What I'm trying to show in my paper is the figure, a description of what it is, and then underneath that an alphabetized list of all the thingies shown in the image, all within the caption.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width = \ImageWidth]{PhysicalExperimentImage}
\centering
\caption{Experimental system used in the validation portion of this experiment.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*)]
    \item Equipment
    \item Sample 1
    \item Sample 2
    \item Sample 3
    \item More equipment
\end{enumerate} 
}
\centering
\label{fig:PhysicalExperiment}
\end{figure}
```

If I move my list outside of the caption (`from begin{enumerate}` to   `\end{enumerate}`)everything compiles just fine. However, when I put it in the braces for the caption section as I have above, I get the following error

> ! Undefined control sequence. \LaTeX3 error:A sequence was
>   misused. }

From what I can tell though, I am closing off everything. Is there something I'm missing, or can I just not do this?

Comment: Try fixing the caption width (with the `caption` package) or putting the list in a `\parbox{some width}`.

Comment: Very close! I tried parbox, which split my opening line in a strange way (the first  is letter left-aligned everything else  in the sentence is right-aligned and the list was fine). But, using minipage with the width set to my \ImageWidth works great. I didn't know about either of these until five minutes ago. Thanks!

Comment: B.t.w., I think of a 3rd possibility: The  `threeparttable` package also defines a `measuredfigure` environment, to be used with `figure` like `threeparttable` is used with `table`. Might be worth testing.

Comment: If should be remembered that \caption formats the caption multiple times, first to see if it will fit in a single line [singlelinesheck=true], then as a paragraph, and finally for use in the list of figures (which in this case should be avoided by using the optional short caption argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Here is one way. Unfortunately I do not have your figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\mycaption{\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
Experimental system used in the validation portion of this experiment.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*)]
    \item Equipment
    \item Sample 1
    \item Sample 2
    \item Sample 3
    \item More equipment
\end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption[short title]{\protect\mycaption}
\label{fig:PhysicalExperiment}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Big thanks to @frougon for suggesting the short title.

Another option is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
\captionof{figure}{Experimental system used in the validation portion of this
experiment.}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*),topsep=-\baselineskip]
    \item Equipment
    \item Sample 1
    \item Sample 2
    \item Sample 3
    \item More equipment
\end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}
\label{fig:PhysicalExperiment}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, may I suggest `\caption[Short title]{\protect\mycaption}` in case one uses `\listoffigures`?

Comment: @frougon Thanks, this is certainly a great suggestion. I am not even sure if the OP want this, or the whole caption in a minipage and done with `\captionof` from the caption package.

Comment: BTW, the example works for me even without `\protect`, but this may be due to the recent changes that made a bunch of commands from the LaTeX kernel robust (I remember `\end` whose implementation is interesting...). So, `\protect` is probably the safe way to go regardless (or use `\NewDocumentCommand` like real men :)).

Comment: @frougon Yes, I am very enthusiastic about some [protected species](https://naturecanada.ca/discover-nature/endangered-species/vancouver-island-marmot/). ;-)

Comment: In this case, you can have a robust species or one that needs special protection every time... Just kidding, `\protect` is fine, I think.

Comment: @frougon Sometimes [protection is really necessary](https://www.canada.ca/content/canadasite/en/environment-climate-change/services/species-risk-public-registry/recovery-strategies/vancouver-island-marmot-2019-proposed/_jcr_content/par/mwsadaptiveimage_1621849844/image.img.jpg/1545936500170.jpg).

Comment: Sure, wild life is not LaTeX... (what does CB mean there?)

Comment: @frougon "captive-bred" .... brrrr

Comment: While I appreciate your interest for wild life, I find it a bit suspicious for a cat to look after rodents. We'll keep an eye on you!

Comment: Both excellent solutions! I wish my setup looked like this duck